# Django filtering for URLs and VIEWS - "Page not found at /collection/..."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls, django-serializer

I am retruning all records for specific object in Django successfully.

My url.py is `path('city/', views.TestListCity.as_view())`
From postman I just GET: http://192.168.99.100:8080/collection/city and it returns all records.
Example:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Bor",
    "region": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Sun"
    }
},
```

Now I want to filter records with column **name.**

I tried this:

```
urls.py
path('city/(?P<name>.+)/$', views.TestListCity.as_view()),

views.py
class TestListCity(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestListCitySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        name = self.kwargs['name']
        return City.objects.filter(name=name)
```

I try GET:

```
http://192.168.99.100:8080/collection/city?name=Bor
```

But then 404:

```
  <title>Page not found at /collection/city</title>
```

I also tried second approach:

```
urls.py
path('city/<str:name>/', views.TestListCity.as_view())

views.py
class TestListCity(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestListCitySerializer
    queryset = City.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'name'
```

But exactly the same response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the below URL (or its equivalent) where the string is a part of the url matching:

```
path('city/<str:name>/$', views.TestListCity.as_view()),
```

Then just call:

```
http://192.168.99.100:8080/collection/city/Bor/
```

Instead of:

```
http://192.168.99.100:8080/collection/city?name=Bor
```

The later one passes `Bor` as the value of the `name` parameter of the `GET` request, i.e. you will need to use something like `name = self.request.GET.get('name')` to get the `name` parameter. It will not be a part of the URL matching.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you used `path()`, and you wanted a regular expression (`re_path()`).

Change this:

```
from django.urls import path
path('city/(?P<name>.+)/$', views.TestListCity.as_view()),
```

to:

```
from django.urls import re_path
re_path('city/(?P<name>.+)/$', views.TestListCity.as_view()),
```

This should work. And maybe the `/` could be optional, like this: `'city/(?P<name>.+)/?$'`